# Identity with repeatedly taking the commutator of a ring element

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

*This is taken from Jacobson's Basic Algebra 2e, it's 2.1.5*

If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a ring, define $a^{(0)} =a, a^{(1)} = [a,b] = ab-ba$ and $a^{(k)}=[a^{(k-1)},b]$ Prove the following formula: $$\sum_{i=0}^k b^i a b^{k-i} = \sum_{j=0}^k {k+1 \choose j+1} b^{k-j}a^{(j)}$$

So, I want to use induction to prove this and have verified it for k=1 and k=2. I've worked on the left hand side and gotten $$\sum_{i=0}^k b^i a b^{k-i} =(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} b^i a b^{(k-1)-i} )b + b^k a $$
The next part would be to make $$ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {k \choose j} b^{(k-1)-j}a^{(j)}$$ appear on the right hand side so that I can apply the inductive hypothesis. The only thing I can think of would be to use ${n+1 \choose k}={n \choose k } + {n \choose k-1}$. Maybe I've made an error but I believe this gives $$\sum_{j=0}^k {k+1 \choose j+1} b^{k-j}a^{(j)}=b(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {k \choose j+1} b^{(k-1)-j}a^{(j)}) + \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}b^{k-j}a^{(j)} + {k \choose k+1}b^0 a^{(k)}$$
While the last term is $0$, because the extra $b$ appears on opposite sides  of the first term, I can't easily equate them and cancel. So I think I'm barking up the wrong tree trying to manipulate the right hand side of the formula in this way.

My question is two fold: how to prove this identity, and what does this composition of the commutator $a^{(j)}$ represent? If it eventually hits 0 is that still some kind of measure for how near $a$ and $b$ are to commuting? If anybody has seen this identity before and it has some usefulness beyond the exercise of proving it, I would also love to hear that.

Comment: I haven't properly thought about your approach yet, but here is the "standard" trick for this sort of identity: Let $A$ be the ring. Let $L : A \to A$ be the map sending each $x$ to $bx$, and let $R : A \to A$ be the map sending each $x$ to $xb$. Then, the operators $L$ and $R$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linear and commute. But the left hand side of your identity is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k L^i R^{k-i} a$, whereas the right hand side is $\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dbinom{k+1}{j+1} L^{k-j} \left(R-L\right)^j a$. So it remains to ...

Comment: ... prove that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k L^i R^{k-i} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dbinom{k+1}{j+1} L^{k-j} \left(R-L\right)^j$. This should follow from binomial-style manipulations (treating $L$ and $R$ as two arbitrary commuting elements).

Comment: Ah, yes, the identity $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k x^i y^{k-i} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^k \dbinom{k+1}{j+1} x^{k-j} \left(y-x\right)^j$ holds for two arbitrary commuting elements $x$ and $y$. To prove it, it suffices to do so when $x$ and $y$ are two commuting indeterminates in a polynomial ring. Multiply both sides by $x-y$ (this is allowed, since $x-y$ is not a zero-divisor in a polynomial ring), so that the left hand side simplifies to $x^{k+1} - y^{k+1}$. Rewrite this using the binomial formula for $y^{k+1} = \left(\left(y-x\right) + x\right)^{k+1}$.

Comment: As to your induction... You want to simplify $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \dbinom{k}{j} b^{\left(k-1\right)-j} a^{(j)} \right) b$ so that it looks more like $\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dbinom{k+1}{j} b^{k-j} a^{(j)}$. So you want to commute the $b$ past the $a^{(j)}$. Of course, it doesn't just commute, but you have $a^{(j)} b = a^{(j+1)} + b a^{(j)}$. So your sum splits into two, with one sum getting its index shifted. I think you can finish it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I outlined two solutions in the comments above; let me expand one of them (the
inductive one) into full detail in order to have this question answered. Be
warned: This is going to be a long computation with no twists or surprises.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements of an (associative, unital,
>   noncommutative) ring $R$. For any $x\in R$ and $y\in R$, we define the
>   *commutator* $\left[  x,y\right]  \in R$ of $x$ and $y$ by $\left[
> x,y\right]  =xy-yx$. Define a sequence $\left(  a^{\left(  0\right)
> },a^{\left(  1\right)  },a^{\left(  2\right)  },\ldots\right)  $ of elements
>   of $R$ recursively by setting
>   \begin{align*}
> a^{\left(  0\right)  }  & =a\qquad\text{and}\\
> a^{\left(  k\right)  }  & =\left[  a^{\left(  k-1\right)  },b\right]
> \qquad\text{for each }k\geq 1.
> \end{align*}
>   Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_{i=0}^{k} b^i ab^{k-i}
> = \sum_{j=0}^{k}\dbinom{k+1}{j+1}b^{k-j}a^{\left( j\right)  }
> \label{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim}
> \tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>   for each nonnegative integer $k$.

*Proof of Theorem 1.* We shall prove \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} by
induction on $k$:

*Induction base:* Comparing
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^0 b^i ab^{0-i}=\underbrace{b^0 }_{=1}a\underbrace{b^{0-0}
}_{=b^0 =1}=a
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^0 \dbinom{0+1}{j+1}b^{0-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
=\underbrace{\dbinom{0+1}{0+1}}_{=1}\underbrace{b^{0-0}}_{=b^0
=1}\underbrace{a^{\left(  0\right)  }}_{=a}=a,
\end{equation}
we obtain $\sum\limits_{i=0}^0 b^i ab^{0-i}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^0 \dbinom{0+1}{j+1}
b^{0-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }$. In other words, \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim}
holds for $k=0$. This completes the induction base.

*Induction step:* Let $K$ be a positive integer. Assume that
\eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} holds for $k=K-1$. We must prove that
\eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} holds for $k=K$.

We have assumed that \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} holds for $k=K-1$. In other
words,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}b^i ab^{\left(  K-1\right)  -i}  & =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}
\dbinom{\left(  K-1\right)  +1}{j+1}b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}a^{\left(
j\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}a^{\left(
j\right)  }
\label{darij1.pf.thm.1.2}
\tag{2}
\end{align}
(since $\left(  K-1\right)  +1=K$).

For every nonnegative integer $j$, we have
\begin{align*}
a^{\left(  j+1\right)  }  & =\left[  a^{\left(  j\right)  },b\right]
\qquad\left(  \text{by the recursive definition of }\left(  a^{\left(
0\right)  },a^{\left(  1\right)  },a^{\left(  2\right)  },\ldots\right)
\right)  \\
& =a^{\left(  j\right)  }b-ba^{\left(  j\right)  }
\end{align*}
(by the definition of $\left[  a^{\left(  j\right)  },b\right]  $) and thus
\begin{equation}
a^{\left(  j\right)  }b=ba^{\left(  j\right)  }+a^{\left(  j+1\right)
}.
\label{darij1.pf.thm.1.3}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Now, we can split off the addend for $i=K$ from the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{K}
b^i ab^{K-i}$. We thus obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{K}b^i ab^{K-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}b^i a\underbrace{b^{K-i}
}_{\substack{=b^{\left(  K-i\right)  -1}b\\\text{(since }K-i\geq
1\\\text{(because }i\leq K-1\text{))}}}+b^{K}a\underbrace{b^{K-K}}_{=b^0 
=1}=\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}b^i ab^{\left(  K-i\right)  -1}b+b^{K}a.
\end{equation}
In view of
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{i=0}^{K-1}b^i a\underbrace{b^{\left(  K-i\right)  -1}}
_{\substack{=b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -i}\\\text{(since }\left(  K-i\right)
-1=\left(  K-1\right)  -i\text{)}}}b\\
& =\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}b^i ab^{\left(  K-1\right)  -i}b=\left(  \sum_{i=0}
^{K-1}b^i ab^{\left(  K-1\right)  -i}\right)  b=\left(  \sum_{j=0}
^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }\right)
b\\
& \qquad\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{this follows by multiplying both sides of}\\
\text{the equality \eqref{darij1.pf.thm.1.2} by }b
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}
\underbrace{a^{\left(  j\right)  }b}_{\substack{=ba^{\left(  j\right)
}+a^{\left(  j+1\right)  }\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.thm.1.3})}}}=\sum
_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}\left(  ba^{\left(
j\right)  }+a^{\left(  j+1\right)  }\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}\underbrace{b^{\left(  K-1\right)  -j}
b}_{\substack{=b^{\left(  \left(  K-1\right)  -j\right)  +1}=b^{K-j}
\\\text{(since }\left(  \left(  K-1\right)  -j\right)  +1=K-j\text{)}
}}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}\underbrace{b^{\left(
K-1\right)  -j}}_{\substack{=b^{K-\left(  j+1\right)  }\\\text{(since }\left(
K-1\right)  -j=K-\left(  j+1\right)  \text{)}}}a^{\left(  j+1\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
+\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-\left(  j+1\right)
}a^{\left(  j+1\right)  }}_{\substack{=\sum_{j=1}^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}
b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }\\\text{(here, we substituted }j\text{ for
}j+1\text{ in the sum)}}}\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+\sum_{j=1}
^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  },
\end{align*}
this rewrites as
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=0}^{K}b^i ab^{K-i}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+\sum_{j=1}
^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+b^{K}
a.
\label{darij1.pf.thm.1.5}
\tag{4}
\end{align}

On the other hand, each nonnegative integer $j$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\dbinom{K+1}{j+1}=\dbinom{K}{j+1}+\dbinom{K}{j}
\label{darij1.pf.thm.1.7}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}
(by the recurrence relation of the binomial coefficients). Also, the
nonnegative integers $K$ and $K+1$ satisfy $K+1 > K$; thus,
\begin{equation}
\dbinom{K}{K+1}=0
\label{darij1.pf.thm.1.8}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
(because any two nonnegative integers $n$ and $k$ satisfying $k>n$ must
satisfy $\dbinom{n}{k}=0$).

Now,
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{j=0}^{K}\underbrace{\dbinom{K+1}{j+1}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{K}
{j+1}+\dbinom{K}{j}\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.thm.1.7})}}}b^{K-j}a^{\left(
j\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K}\left(  \dbinom{K}{j+1}+\dbinom{K}{j}\right)  b^{K-j}
a^{\left(  j\right)  }\\
& =\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{K}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
}_{\substack{=\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)
}+\dbinom{K}{K+1}b^{K-K}a^{\left(  K\right)  }\\\text{(here, we have split off
the addend for }j=K\text{ from the sum)}}}\\
& \qquad+\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
}_{\substack{=\sum_{j=1}^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
+\dbinom{K}{0}b^{K-0}a^{\left(  0\right)  }\\\text{(here, we have split off
the addend for }j=0\text{ from the sum)}}}\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
+\underbrace{\dbinom{K}{K+1}}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(by
\eqref{darij1.pf.thm.1.8})}}}b^{K-K}a^{\left(  K\right)  }\\
& \qquad+\sum_{j=1}^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }
+\underbrace{\dbinom{K}{0}}_{=1}\underbrace{b^{K-0}}_{=b^{K}}
\underbrace{a^{\left(  0\right)  }}_{=a}\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\dbinom{K}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+\sum_{j=1}
^{K}\dbinom{K}{j}b^{K-j}a^{\left(  j\right)  }+b^{K}a.
\end{align*}
Comparing this with \eqref{darij1.pf.thm.1.5}, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{K}b^i ab^{K-i}=\sum_{j=0}^{K}\dbinom{K+1}{j+1}b^{K-j}a^{\left(
j\right)  }.
\end{equation}
In other words, \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} holds for $k=K$. This completes
the induction step. Thus, \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} is proven by
induction. Hence, Theorem 1 follows. $\blacksquare$

**Remark.** Theorem 1 also holds if $R$ is a nonunital ring, provided that we interpret all the expressions appearing in \eqref{darij1.eq.thm.1.claim} appropriately. (For example, a product of the form "$b^0 a$" has to be interpreted as $a$ even though its sub-expression "$b^0$" is not defined.) The proof we gave above still applies to this situation.